# Set treemap colour by categories in Plotly in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to set colour by different continent in Plotly. I am wondering on how to achieve this.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale=['#32a852', '#3261a8', '#a83259'],
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

Comment: The example in the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#treemap-chart-with-a-continuous-colorscale) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving heavy lifting to **Plotly Express**, once figure is built modify `marker_color` **list**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.treemap(
    df,
    path=[px.Constant("world"), "continent", "country"],
    values="pop",
    color="lifeExp",
    hover_data=["iso_alpha"],
    color_continuous_scale=["#32a852", "#3261a8", "#a83259"],
    color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df["lifeExp"], weights=df["pop"]),
)
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
cm = {
    "Asia": "red",
    "Africa": "yellow",
    "Americas": "white",
    "Europe": "blue",
    "Oceania": "black",
}
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda t: t.update(
        marker_colors=[
            cm[id.split("/")[1]] if len(id.split("/")) == 2 else c
            for c, id in zip(t.marker.colors, t.ids)
        ]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!